# Magento 2.3.5 Content Security Policy false positive cdn fonts

Tags: magento2.3, upgrade, magento2.3.5

Since the update of 2.3.5 that came out today Magento built in "Content Security Policy" and that's great but now I'm wondering how to ignore/whitelist CDN font's that are now being reported as a false positive in the console log. 
Also it says Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

Does someone have more experience with "Content Security Policy" that can help me out?

```
[Report Only] Refused to load the script 'https://kit.fontawesome.com/a0b92fa8c0.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: 
"script-src assets.adobedtm.com geostag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com geoapi.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafapi.cardinalcommerce.com songbird.cardinalcommerce.com includestest.ccdc02.com www.googleadservices.com www.google-analytics.com secure.authorize.net test.authorize.net www.paypal.com www.sandbox.paypal.com www.paypalobjects.com t.paypal.com s.ytimg.com video.google.com vimeo.com www.vimeo.com js.authorize.net jstest.authorize.net js.braintreegateway.com cdn-scripts.signifyd.com www.youtube.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". 
Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Comment: Also to add to this further reading of the release notes as of 2.4.0 any not whitelisted will be blocked.

Comment: We are also gettings hundreds of notices and errors.

Comment: @Riccardo please let me know what is the use of this file csp_whitelist.xml why should we use this. can u please clarify

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## etc/csp_whitelist.xml

Need to implement our own whitelist using above file

*see https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/security/content-security-policies.html*

#### pros:

- format evaluation using schema

#### cons:

- there is no way to declare schema type entry
- however you can whitelist schemes declaring host with schema name, just need to add : after the schema name eg: `<value id="data-schema" type="host">data:</value>`

### this is the recommended way by Magento

---

## etc/config.xml

whitelist can be declared as config node with specific tags using above file

*see vendor/magento/module-csp/etc/config.xml*

#### pros:

- can be inserted to the *core_config_data* table via environment configuration or data patch

#### cons:

- if it is stored in DB data patch required to change/modify

---

## Implement custom policy collector

*see vendor/magento/module-csp/etc/di.xml and vendor/magento/module-csp/Model/Collector/CspWhitelistXmlCollector.php*

- inject your custom collector into collectors argument of Magento\Csp\Model\CompositePolicyCollector.
- Custom collector have to implements Magento\Csp\Api\PolicyCollectorInterface
- insert policies using Magento\Csp\Model\Policy\FetchPolicy

#### pros:

- you can use nonce type whitelists
- highly customizable
- possible to create standard, composer ready solution with chance to adjust whitelist thru configuration (eg using https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ext-best-practices/tutorials/dynamic-row-system-config.html to store whitlelist element)

#### cons:

- developer knowledge required

Answer (score 19):

Hello I am also just about to read in. If you have an own module in the app/code then you must create the following file.

app/code/modul_modul/etc/csp_whitelist.xml

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright  Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="script-src">
            <values>
                <!--CDN-->
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>

                <!--Google-->
                <value id="google-analytics" type="host">www.google-analytics.com</value>

                <!--Functions-->
                <value id="trustedshops" type="host">*.trustedshops.com</value>
                <value id="usercentrics" type="host">*.usercentrics.eu</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="style-src">
            <values>
                <!--CDN-->
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>

                <!--Design-->
                <value id="typekit" type="host">*.typekit.net</value>

                <!--Functions-->
                <value id="trustedshops" type="host">*.trustedshops.com</value>
                <value id="usercentrics" type="host">*.usercentrics.eu</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="img-src">
            <values>
                <!--CDN-->
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="klarna-base" type="host">https://cdn.klarna.com</value>

                <!--Payments-->
                <value id="paypal" type="host">*.paypal.com</value>

                <!--Video-->
                <value id="vimeocdn" type="host">*.vimeocdn.com</value>
                <value id="youtube-img" type="host">https://s.ytimg.com</value>

                <!--Functions-->
                <value id="usercentrics" type="host">*.usercentrics.eu</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="connect-src">
            <values>
                <!--CDN-->
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>

                <!--Payments-->
                <value id="paypal" type="host">*.paypal.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="font-src">
            <values>
                <!--CDN-->
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>

                <!--Design-->
                <value id="typekit" type="host">*.typekit.net</value>

                <!--Functions-->
                <value id="trustedshops" type="host">*.trustedshops.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```

in your case

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright  Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="script-src">
            <values>
                <value id="fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```

Comment: For a theme script placed from MyTheme/default/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml in     `<head>
        <link src="js/myscript.js"/>
    </head>` , where should the csp_whitelist.xml be placed? In MyTheme/default/etc/csp_whitelist.xml? Because I tried to place it there but it doesn't work.

Comment: @KaMZaTa No in the theme does not work, as specified you should have your own module: app/code/modul_modul/etc/csp_whitelist.xml

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work either. I run `magento setup:upgrade` and `magento c:f` after created the new module but nothing to do. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @Materix, carefully followed your solution, yet there is no difference. What am I missing?

Comment: @Materix How to fix this issue https://prnt.sc/tcj9ee can u suggest me

Comment: @NagarajuK https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312056/magento-2-3-5-p1-csp-font-src-self-unsafe-inline `<policy id="font-src">
            <values>
    <value id="data" type="host">'self' data:</value><value id="data" type="host">data:</value>
            </values>
        </policy>`

Comment: @CodeForGood Did you make your own module for this? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312056/magento-2-3-5-p1-csp-font-src-self-unsafe-inline#answer-312350

Comment: @Materix, no, didn't create a module for it.

Comment: @CodeForGood Should be done in a separate module. This should work: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312056/magento-2-3-5-p1-csp-font-src-self-unsafe-inline#answer-312350 do not forget to adjust the namespace :-)

Comment: Thanks, will try when I take this task back. I dropped this a few weeks ago owing to the complexity.

Comment: I am in localhost with `http` only. Error: `because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src *.typekit.net *.googleapis.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".` Any thoughts?

Comment: @Materix How can i fix the  -> refused to load the script 'https://bam.nr-data.net/1/NRJS-3e9ed1fc777f7318b53?a=999874198&v=1215.1253ab8&to=blEHYEcEXRFWWkANDFcbJFdBDFwMGFpVEAJVWwIbVgRHB1BWRh1MT10AQw%3D%3D&rst=1768&ck=1&ref

I added the *.newrelic.com value in my custom module CSP xml file

Answer (score 2):

You can just disable `Magento_Csp` entirely in Magento `2.3.5` since it offers little or no value.

More info https://maxchadwick.xyz/blog/magento-2-3-5-csp-fools-errand https://maxchadwick.xyz/blog/magento-disable-csp

Comment: Thanks for the info but I've read that it will be obligated in the newer versions of Magento to come so I don't know if disabling is the right way to go ..

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
<policy id="script-src">
        <values>
            <value id="fontawesome-com" type="host">fontawesome.com</value>
        </values>
    </policy>
</csp_whitelist>
```

Answer (score 0):

as said by Materix, put the xml in the etc folder.
I put that file in the following path:
/app/code/Magento/Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xml

I wish it could help someone.

Answer (score 0):

CSP Informations for Google Services: [developers.google.com/tag-manager/web/csp](http://developers.google.com/tag-manager/web/csp)