# Magento 2.3.5 Content Security Policy (CSP) data:image

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.5

Has anyone found a way to integrate the data:image/png as csp_whitelist?

[Report Only] Refused to load the image 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR4nGP6zwAAAgcBApocMXEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src widgets.magentocommerce.com www.googleadservices.com www.google-analytics.com t.paypal.com www.paypal.com www.paypalobjects.com fpdbs.paypal.com fpdbs.sandbox.paypal.com *.vimeocdn.com s.ytimg.com *.cloudflare.com https://cdn.klarna.com *.paypal.com https://s.ytimg.com *.usercentrics.eu 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".

Comment: Facing same issue here after updating to 2.3.5 have go any news? could be a Bug!

Comment: @Juliano Vargas, how to fix this?

Comment: @CodeForGood I've used this sample from magento docs ref: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/security/content-security-policies.html#add-a-domain-to-the-whitelist:

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your custom csp_whitelist.xml (eg. in a custom modules etc-directory) add this:

```
<policy id="img-src">
  <values>
    <value id="data" type="host">data:</value>
  </values>
</policy>
```

The colon as suffix is the important stuff here.

Comment: it fix issue but it looks like dirty workaround. Hm

Comment: thanks, this will work

Comment: @KonradSiamro AFAIK the data: should be declared as scheme and not as host in the CSP regarding the CSP-specification, but the Magento-CSP-Module only supports host and hash as type - no support for real scheme-policies right now.

Comment: ok, thanks for explanation

Comment: @Tobias Wassermann, I have been trying to fix the similar issue post upgrade to 2.3.5. Could you please look at my post and suggest a possible solution  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/314451/magento-2-3-5-after-the-successful-upgrade-to-2-3-5-using-composer-there-are-a

Answer (score 0):

> You can add a domain to the whitelist for a policy (like script-src,
>   style-src, font-src and others) by adding a csp_whitelist.xml to your
>   custom module’s etc folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="script-src">
            <values>
                <value id="devdocs-base" type="host">https://devdocs.magento.com</value>
                <value id="magento" type="host">https://magento.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="connect-src">
            <values>
                <value id="devdocs" type="host">https://devdocs.magento.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```

From: 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/security/content-security-policies.html

Related: [Magento 2.3.5 Content Security Policy false positive cdn fonts](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311661/magento-2-3-5-content-security-policy-false-positive-cdn-fonts/311722#311722)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in this case I'm mainly interested in the images/fonts/scripts with data:image/png;base64, data:application/javascript;base64, data:application/font-woff;base64

Comment: Do you need clear cache or something after doing this? It doesn't work for me

Comment: @KaMZaTa https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311661/magento-2-3-5-content-security-policy-false-positive-cdn-fonts/311722#311722

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Did it work for you? I'm trying to whitelisting a script added in <head> through layout/default.xml file and placed in my_theme/web/js/myscript.js. It load the script but it is not whitelisted.

Comment: I tried to set "default-src" instead "script-scr" but it doesn't work as well. I placed my csp_whitelist.xml in app/code/design/frontend/MyTheme/default/etc/csp_whitelist.xml. Is that correct? Did you notice original one is called csp_whitelist.xsd instead?

Comment: @KaMZaTa, Did you finally fix all of them? Please let me know

Comment: @CodeForGood no, I’m not. If I got well CSP in Magento is pretty buggy so I decided to fix it later.

Comment: @KaMZaTa, Is there way to turn off these errors/notices so that they don't appear on the frontend? Thanks

Comment: @paj, I have been trying to fix the similar issue post upgrade to 2.3.5. Could you please look at my post and suggest a possible solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/314451/magento-2-3-5-after-the-successful-upgrade-to-2-3-5-using-composer-there-are-a

Comment: @CodeForGood just disable the module: `magento module:disable Magento_Csp`

Comment: @KaMZaTa, isn't it a temporary solution to disable the module?

Comment: @CodeForGood I didn't get you. What do you mean?

Comment: Did anyone manage to make it work on themes? as for me it's not working at all only under a Custom/Module.

Answer (score 0):

If the above solution will not work then try the below one.

```
<policy id="img-src">
  <values>
    <value id="data-image" type="host">'self' data:</value>
  </values>
</policy>
```

It is working in the Magento2.4.2 commerce version.