# Magento 2.3.5 Content Security Policy directive: "img-src

Tags: security, magento2.3.5

**Upgrade to 2.3.5 and now getting this error bellow thought out the site on every page:**

> [Report Only] Refused to load the image
>   'blob:http://my.domayn.com/axxxxxxxxxxxx' because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src
>   widgets.magentocommerce.com www.googleadservices.com
>   www.google-analytics.com t.paypal.com www.paypal.com
>   www.paypalobjects.com fpdbs.paypal.com fpdbs.sandbox.paypal.com
>   *.vimeocdn.com s.ytimg.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".

Is anyone facing the same issue?

Comment: Yes, I am having the same problem when I upgrade the Magento2.3.4 to 2.3.5=p1,  even in fresh Magento.

- I read [https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/security/content-security-policies.html] but everything is gone on my head.

- How to resolve it?

Comment: Related: - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311661/magento-2-3-5-content-security-policy-false-positive-cdn-fonts - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311724/magento-2-3-5-content-security-policy-csp-dataimage

Answer (score 11):

As of version 2.3.5, Magento supports Content Security Policy headers and provides ways to configure them.

> Content Security Policies (CSP) are a powerful tool to mitigate
>   against Cross Site Scripting (XSS) and related attacks, including card
>   skimmers, session hijacking, clickjacking, and more.

By default, Content Security Policiy is configured in **report-only mode**, which allows merchants and developers to configure policies to work according to their custom code.

*Your browser is not showing a Magento 2 error, it is reporting a CSP policy violation*

You can configure your own custom CSP rules by adding a csp_whitelist.xml to a custom module etc folder.

You can find more information on how to do this here.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/security/content-security-policies.html

To completely disable CSP you can also try

```
bin/magento module:disable Magento_Csp
```

Comment: Hi @paj

In fresh magento2.3.5-p1, I am having the same issue So what I need to whitelist for fresh Magento.

Comment: This covers custom module, what about Magento's core modules? These reports are showing up for fresh installation of Magento.

Comment: Why does the magento team not whitelist their own stuff for a fresh magento 2 ??

Answer (score 3):

This works for me - csp_whitelist.xml

```
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp:etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="img-src">
            <values>
                <value id="blob" type="host">blob:</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```