# Magento 2.3.5: The content security policy related notices in the browser console after Magento upgrade to 2.3.5

Tags: magento2.3, frontend, magento-upgrade, csp

Upgrading to 2.3.5 has lead to hundreds of notices in the front end as seen in the screenshot below. The devdoc explaining the CSP isn't detailed enough to find a solution to this. Can anyone show with an example by choosing one of the notices from the screenshot below how to whitelist it?

[image]

Comment: Have you seen dev docs https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/security/content-security-policies.html

Comment: Looking at the document now. Thanks Dominic.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311661/magento-2-3-5-content-security-policy-false-positive-cdn-fonts/311722#311722

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311724/magento-2-3-5-content-security-policy-csp-dataimage?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Materix, thanks, could you please pick one of the notices from the screenshot above and write a code of line to demonstrate how I can continue with the rest. I looked at the post referred to  by the link above and cannot understand it well.