# Magento 2.3.5-p1 CSP font-src self unsafe-inline

Tags: magento2, security, csp

In regarding to CSP I create own csp_whitelist, but still I am getting:

> The Content Security Policy 'font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
>   form-action secure.authorize.net test.authorize.net
>   geostag.cardinalcommerce.com geo.cardinalcommerce.com
>   1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eaf.cardinalcommerce.com
>   centinelapistag.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapi.cardinalcommerce.com
>   'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-ancestors 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
>   frame-src secure.authorize.net test.authorize.net
>   geostag.cardinalcommerce.com geo.cardinalcommerce.com
>   1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eaf.cardinalcommerce.com
>   centinelapistag.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapi.cardinalcommerce.com
>   www.paypal.com www.sandbox.paypal.com https://js.stripe.com/
>   https://www.googletagmanager.com/ https://www.google.com/ 'self'
>   'unsafe-inline'; img-src widgets.magentocommerce.com
>   www.googleadservices.com www.google-analytics.com t.paypal.com
>   www.paypal.com www.paypalobjects.com fpdbs.paypal.com
>   fpdbs.sandbox.paypal.com *.vimeocdn.com s.ytimg.com
>   https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/ data: 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
>   script-src assets.adobedtm.com js.authorize.net jstest.authorize.net
>   secure.authorize.net test.authorize.net geostag.cardinalcommerce.com
>   1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com geoapi.cardinalcommerce.com
>   1eafapi.cardinalcommerce.com songbird.cardinalcommerce.com
>   includestest.ccdc02.com www.googleadservices.com
>   www.google-analytics.com www.paypal.com www.sandbox.paypal.com
>   www.paypalobjects.com t.paypal.com js.braintreegateway.com s.ytimg.com
>   video.google.com vimeo.com www.vimeo.com cdn-scripts.signifyd.com
>   www.youtube.com https://js.stripe.com/v3/
>   https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js
>   https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js https://www.gstatic.com/
>   'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src getfirebug.com 'self'
>   'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src 'self'
>   'unsafe-inline'; manifest-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src
>   geostag.cardinalcommerce.com geo.cardinalcommerce.com
>   1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eaf.cardinalcommerce.com
>   centinelapistag.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapi.cardinalcommerce.com
>   'self' 'unsafe-inline'; child-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; default-src
>   'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; base-uri 'self'
>   'unsafe-inline';' was delivered in report-only mode, but does not
>   specify a 'report-uri'; the policy will have no effect. Please either
>   add a 'report-uri' directive, or deliver the policy via the
>   'Content-Security-Policy' header.

Can I fix it using csp_whitelist.xml?

Edit:
I tried to add some those domains as host to font-src, but it doesnt solve issue. I mean, domains didn`t disappear from warning

.

**EDIT && Solutions:**

For issue I wrote here (`The Content Security Policy 'font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';`). It is enough to set up `report_uri` in Your `csp_whitelist.xml` file.

For issue with `data:xxx` is enough to add

> ```
> <policy id="font-src">
>     <values>
>         <value id="data" type="host">data:</value>
>     </values>
> </policy>
> ```

to Your `csp_whitelist.xml` file.
Of course You should add `data:` policy depends on scope where You have problem (policy id should be changed for example to img-src etc).
It is necessary to set is as `host`, cause right now Magento doesn`t read any other types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the end of the console report, it says:

`"...was delivered in report-only mode, but does not specify a 'report-uri'; the policy will have no effect. Please either add a 'report-uri' directive, or deliver the policy via the 'Content-Security-Policy' header."`

This is not saying that the the domain values for each of the listed policies are not whitelisted, they are by default (this error made me believe they weren't until I really looked at it closer). It's saying that there is no `report-uri` directive.

From the [devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/security/content-security-policies.html#report-uri-configuration), it says:

`Regardless of restrict or report-only mode, CSP violations may be reported to an endpoint for collection. The URL to use for reporting by browsers can be configured in your custom module’s config.xml file:`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <csp>
            <mode>
                <storefront>
                    <report_uri>http://csp-reporting-service.com/my-project/endpoint</report_uri>
                </storefront>
                <admin>
                    <report_uri>http://csp-reporting-service.com/my-project/endpoint</report_uri>
                </admin>
            </mode>
        </csp>
    </default>
</config>
```

**By default, CSP sends errors to the browser console, but can be configured to collect error logs by HTTP request. In addition, there are a number of third-party services that you can use to monitor, collect, and report CSP violations. So, either configure it to be reported to the error logs by https request, or create a custom module and configure the report_uri directive with the CSP reporting service of your liking.**
https://devdocs.magento.com/security/content-security-policy-overview.html

Comment: Hey, thanks. I was not sure about that. I will not use report-uri for now so I couldn`t test it.

Comment: I tested this today but could not get the report-uri config to work. One other way to resolve this is simply to disable the Magento_Csp module...

Comment: @paj Disabling the module would certainly stop the reports in the console, however it's not a solution to the problem.

Comment: @MagentoAaron Depends if you want this feature or not - as a Magento Merchant I didn't ask for CSP to be implemented in Magento 2.3.5 - the option to disable it would have been nice!

Comment: @paj They provided you with a way to disable it, it's called `Report Only`. It's in fact disabled by default. If the reports in the console are a bother, you can configure the violations to be reported to error logs.

Comment: @MagentoAaron one small query for the production site (or) UAT instance which mode should be enabled restrict / read-only? please advise

Comment: @Nagaraju K - The recommendation should be `Restrict`. But you'll have to set it to `Report Only` unless you have your Content Security Policy up-to-date and confirmed working. If you don't have it properly configured and you enable `Restrict` mode, then those resources would be blocked from loading.

Comment: Thanks for your advise @MagentoAaron

Answer (score 26):

Magento 2.3.5 p1 added a new module module-csp ( Magento_Csp ) which supports Content Security Policies ( CSP ) headers and provides ways to configure them. The policies can be configured for backend and frontend areas both.

Content Security Policies ( CSP ) has two modes – report-only and restrict. In Magento 2.3.5 p1, the default mode is report-only which is shows the policy violations in the browser's console. You can configure these csp for all third party loaded content as per your custom modules and theme.

I was able to solve all the policy errors for my site by creating a custom module.

app/code/Namespace/Csp/registration.php

```
<?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        'Namespace_Csp',
        __DIR__
    );
```

app/code/Namespace/Csp/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Namespace_Csp" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

app/code/Namespace/Csp/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <csp>
            <mode>
                <storefront>
                    <report_uri>https://www.example.com/</report_uri>
                </storefront>
                <admin>
                    <report_uri>https://www.example.com/</report_uri>
                </admin>
            </mode>
            
        </csp>
    </default>
</config>
```

app/code/Namespace/Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="script-src">
            <values>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="google-analytics" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
                <value id="google" type="host">*.google.com</value>
                <value id="twimg" type="host">*.twimg.com</value>
                <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                <value id="trustedshops" type="host">*.trustedshops.com</value>
                <value id="usercentrics" type="host">*.usercentrics.eu</value>
                <value id="fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="style-src">
            <values>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="googleapis" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="twimg" type="host">*.twimg.com</value>
                <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                <value id="typekit" type="host">*.typekit.net</value>
                <value id="trustedshops" type="host">*.trustedshops.com</value>
                <value id="usercentrics" type="host">*.usercentrics.eu</value>
                <value id="fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
                
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="img-src">
            <values>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="klarna-base" type="host">*.klarna.com</value>
                <value id="googleadservices" type="host">*.googleadservices.com</value>
                <value id="google-analytics" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
                <value id="paypal" type="host">*.paypal.com</value>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="twimg" type="host">*.twimg.com</value>
                <value id="vimeocdn" type="host">*.vimeocdn.com</value>
                <value id="youtube-img" type="host">*.ytimg.com</value>
                <value id="data" type="host">'self' data:</value>
                <value id="lightemporium" type="host">*.lightemporium.com</value>                
                <value id="usercentrics" type="host">*.usercentrics.eu</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="connect-src">
            <values>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="paypal" type="host">*.paypal.com</value>
                <value id="twimg" type="host">*.twimg.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="font-src">
            <values>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                <value id="typekit" type="host">*.typekit.net</value>
                <value id="twimg" type="host">*.twimg.com</value>
                <value id="trustedshops" type="host">*.trustedshops.com</value>
                <value id="googleapis" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        
        <policy id="frame-src">
            <values>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        
        <policy id="form-action">
            <values>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```

Add your thirdparty urls/domains to csp_whitelist.xml. All suggestions are most welcome

Comment: how to set dynamic domain name in config.xml file as for my staging website it will be a different URL. you have hardcoded the domain - https://www.example.com/

Comment: Why the magento team did not deliver such a module, why do we have to create it ourselve??? And why is everything hardcoded, you should be able to configure it from the backend.

Comment: Thanks for the module, please add  <?php
  in the beginning of your app/code/Namespace/Csp/registration.php

Comment: @suman What about multistore website? Can we use multiple storefront in config.xml

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me:

**https://maxchadwick.xyz/blog/magento-disable-csp**

**How To Disable Content Security Policy (CSP)**
The best way to disable Content Security Policy is to disable the `Magento_Csp` module:

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Csp
```

Please read that article for more details

Comment: This means that you are disabling a security feature and you enable cross site scripting attacks (XSS). You are supposed to whitelist the allowed domains and then set the extension from report only mode to restrict mode.

Answer (score 2):

to fix this issue please use this module - https://github.com/Anantkprajapati/AKP_CSP

Answer (score 1):

To whitelist `data:font` and `data:application`

```
    <policy id="font-src">
        <values>
            <value id="data" type="host">'self' data:</value>
        </values>
    </policy>
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

To clean up these errors you have to create a module and implement a file called `etc/csp_whitelist.xml`. In this file, you might be able to whitelist domains or files.

One of the things I didn't figure yet is how to whitelist `data:font` and `data:application`.

Comment: I did it.  You can do work around and put `data:` as host (instead of domain). Its not great, but its the only one way to fix errors with `data:xxx` right now. It is because magento csp_whitelist works only with `host` parameter.

Comment: You cannot prevent the OP's specific report in the console with the `etc/csp_whitelist.xml` file. This specific report is a result of the `report-uri`directive not being configured.

Comment: @KonradSiamro thanks! I confirm, your method works.

Answer (score 0):

While you develop your own module for to fix the [issue](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/security/content-security-policies.html#report-uri-configuration), you can disable Magento_Csp module, just to stop the show error on console. This will not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've created Magento 2 module to collect CSP reports and automatically generate rules to eliminate warning spam in browser console. You can try to use it - https://github.com/flancer32/mage2_ext_csp

This module does not add `data:` rule automatically at the moment. You need to add this rule manually (using SQL) directly to DB.

Answer (score 0):

This big message means you're in **report-only** CSP mode. Logically it assumes you have a report url to use this mode. If you don't have report uri, you can set the mode to **restrict** by adding this to your `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <csp>
            <mode>
                <storefront>
                    <report_only>0</report_only>
                </storefront>
                <admin>
                    <report_only>0</report_only>
                </admin>
            </mode>
        </csp>
    </default>
</config>
```

Resource https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/security/content-security-policies.html#configure-a-modules-csp-mode

Answer (score 0):

It has mentioned in 2.4.3 release Magento doc., this is still a known issue with Magento: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/open-source-2-4-3.html#known-issues. So, we can do is a temporary fix for being time.

The solution is to creating own custom module to extending the Magento_Csp module. In the etc/config.xml file we want to modify the frame-ancestor policy and set it to 0.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
<default>
    <csp>
        <policies>
            <storefront>
                <frame-ancestors>
                    <inline>0</inline>
                </frame-ancestors>
            </storefront>
            <admin>
                <frame-ancestors>
                    <inline>0</inline>
                </frame-ancestors>
            </admin>
        </policies>
    </csp>
</default>
```

Then run:

```
bin/magento s:up
bin/magento c:f
```

This will help it's a working solution.

Happy Coding!!