# The Content Security Policy was delivered in report-only mode, but does not specify a 'report-uri'

Tags: magento2

How can I fix this error, which is showing in the browser console in the customers backend area:

> The Content Security Policy 'font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
> form-action secure.authorize.net test.authorize.net
> geostag.cardinalcommerce.com geo.cardinalcommerce.com
> 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eaf.cardinalcommerce.com
> centinelapistag.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapi.cardinalcommerce.com
> 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-ancestors 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
> frame-src secure.authorize.net test.authorize.net
> geostag.cardinalcommerce.com geo.cardinalcommerce.com
> 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eaf.cardinalcommerce.com
> centinelapistag.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapi.cardinalcommerce.com
> [www.paypal.com](http://www.paypal.com) [www.sandbox.paypal.com](http://www.sandbox.paypal.com) 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src
> widgets.magentocommerce.com [www.googleadservices.com](http://www.googleadservices.com)
> [www.google-analytics.com](http://www.google-analytics.com) t.paypal.com [www.paypal.com](http://www.paypal.com)
> [www.paypalobjects.com](http://www.paypalobjects.com) fpdbs.paypal.com fpdbs.sandbox.paypal.com
> *.vimeocdn.com s.ytimg.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src assets.adobedtm.com secure.authorize.net test.authorize.net
> geostag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com
> geoapi.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafapi.cardinalcommerce.com
> songbird.cardinalcommerce.com includestest.ccdc02.com
> commerce.adobedtm.com js.authorize.net jstest.authorize.net
> [www.googleadservices.com](http://www.googleadservices.com) [www.google-analytics.com](http://www.google-analytics.com) [www.paypal.com](http://www.paypal.com)
> [www.sandbox.paypal.com](http://www.sandbox.paypal.com) [www.paypalobjects.com](http://www.paypalobjects.com) t.paypal.com
> js.braintreegateway.com use.typekit.net p.typekit.net
> amcglobal.sc.omtrdc.net commerce.adobe.net magento-recs-sdk.adobe.net
> s.ytimg.com video.google.com vimeo.com [www.vimeo.com](http://www.vimeo.com)
> cdn-scripts.signifyd.com [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com) 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
> 'unsafe-eval'; style-src getfirebug.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
> object-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
> manifest-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src api.magento.com
> geostag.cardinalcommerce.com geo.cardinalcommerce.com
> 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eaf.cardinalcommerce.com
> centinelapistag.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapi.cardinalcommerce.com
> commerce.adobedtm.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; child-src 'self'
> 'unsafe-inline'; default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
> base-uri 'self' 'unsafe-inline';' was delivered in report-only mode,
> but does not specify a 'report-uri'; the policy will have no effect.
> Please either add a 'report-uri' directive, or deliver the policy via
> the 'Content-Security-Policy' header.

I have no idea why this error shows, please help.

Comment: Please check this post if it helps! https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312056/magento-2-3-5-p1-csp-font-src-self-unsafe-inline

Answer (score 1):

If you are the site admin, you can add a module with this configuration in `config.xml`:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/security/content-security-policies.html#report-uri-configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <csp>
            <mode>
                <storefront>
                    <report_uri>http://csp-reporting-service.com/my-project/endpoint</report_uri>
                </storefront>
                <admin>
                    <report_uri>http://csp-reporting-service.com/my-project/endpoint</report_uri>
                </admin>
            </mode>
        </csp>
    </default>
</config>
```

(it also works with 2.3.5, not just 2.4)

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, the report URI is an endpoint on your website where the browser sends the CSP reports to. It can be a fake URL if you don't need the reports. If you need them, create an endpoint that accepts the reports through `php://input`.

A more comprehensive explanation can be found at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/report-uri

Comment: Why "http://csp-reporting-service.com/my-project/endpoint" ?

Comment: The `report_uri` is an endpoint on your website. You pick the URL, I'm not sure if there is a built-in page in Magento (I assume there isn't, otherwise they would have put it in the doc). How the endpoint has to work is explained here (I will add this to the answer): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/report-uri
Finally, you can put a fake URL if you don't need the reporting.

Answer (score 0):

See here
https://sherocommerce.com/magento-content-security-policy/

They suggest using https://report-uri.com/r/d/csp/reportOnly as the url

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/199997)

Comment: The answer is the second line