# Magento 2 Content Security Policy: The page’s settings observed the loading of a resource at https://xuz/font-awesome.min.css (“style-src”)

Tags: magento2, javascript, css, meta-tags, csp

We transfer hosting to another hosting company everything is working fine but we are getting console errors in firefox like this - "The page’s settings observed the loading of a resource at https://xuz/font-awesome.min.css (“style-src”). A CSP report is being sent."

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: It looks like you have an issue with Content Security Policy. Have you look at this question and its answers https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311661/magento-2-3-5-content-security-policy-false-positive-cdn-fonts. Is it related to your issue?

Comment: @djm.im ok checking

Comment: yes i done on my localhost need to be done on live